# Maps.newTreeMap vs new TreeMap

Tags: maps, treemap

There are two ways to construct a `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap treeMap1 = Maps.newTreeMap();
TreeMap treeMap2 = new TreeMap();
```

What is the difference? Are they the same or one is over the other?